# Strange behavior when converting typescript to java script

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am trying to move my NodeJs app from Java Script to TypeScript to take advantage of some of the avail benefits. But while doing so i fail at the most simple taks..

I have this simple code below in my index.ts file. I want to import express and then start a basic listener on the port from the config file.

```
import {express} from 'express';
import {config} from './config/config';
    
const app = express();
const http = require('http');

const secure = http.createServer(app).listen(config.port ,()=>{
    console.log(`listening on Port ${config.port}`)
})
```

when i run "npm run-script build" i get the below output

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const express_1 = require("express");
const config_1 = require("./config/config");
const app = express_1.express();
const http = require('http');
var secure = http.createServer(app).listen(config_1.config.port, () => {
    console.log(`listening on Port ${config_1.config.port}`);
});
```

why does it prefix express and config with _1 ? The express_1.express seems to brake it. Hope someone can tell my why and how to avoid in future.

Comment: Do you have a specific error? Typescript will change variable names for a couple of reasons. You don't really have control over that, though.

Comment: Javascript is usually transpiled before it's run by various build tools that do all sorts of stuff, like combine multiple files into a single file, changes the names of variables/functions, minify code, etc.. What's the actual error you're getting and where in the **source** code is it occurring?

Comment: In my case it does not create an error when i build it but when I try to run the JS code. I get the following error const app = express_1.express();TypeError: express_1.express is not a function

Comment: If i change my lines to  const express = require("express");const app = express(); all works as expected..

Answer (score 0):

I think express module is not a named export it's a default export. for that you've to import like below to make it work.

```
import express from 'express';
```